# OPC UA sdk linker

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, opc

I compiled source code and make .o files, but linker still returns mistakes below.
There is undefined reference to constructor UaMutexLocker and others as you can see below. I added path to library -luabasecppd where is this contained, but I don't have any idea, why it doesn't work.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:244: undefined reference to `UaMutex::UaMutex()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:247: undefined reference to `UaThread::start()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:244: undefined reference to `UaMutex::~UaMutex()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:244: undefined reference to `UaThread::~UaThread()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::~UaReverseEndpoint()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:252: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:254: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:257: undefined reference to `UaThread::wait(unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:261: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::lock(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:268: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:252: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:249: undefined reference to `UaMutex::~UaMutex()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:249: undefined reference to `UaThread::~UaThread()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::registerSession(UaString const&, UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointCallback*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:280: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:280: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:280: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::registerDiscovery(UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointCallback*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:297: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:297: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:297: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::unregisterSession(UaString const&, UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointCallback*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:319: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:319: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:319: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::unregisterDiscovery(UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointCallback*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:339: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:339: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:339: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::run()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:349: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:369: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:379: undefined reference to `UaThread::msleep(unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:381: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::lock(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:349: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:349: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::beginConnect()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:393: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:406: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:445: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::lock(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:447: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:451: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::lock(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:393: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:393: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::disconnect()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:468: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:468: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:468: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::removeChannel(void*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:492: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:492: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:492: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint::invalidateChannel(void*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:505: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:505: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:505: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointList::UaReverseEndpointList()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:524: undefined reference to `UaMutex::UaMutex()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointList::~UaReverseEndpointList()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:527: undefined reference to `UaMutex::~UaMutex()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointList::getReverseEndpoint(UaString const&)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:534: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:534: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:534: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointList::decrementEndpoint(UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpoint*)':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:552: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:560: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:552: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:552: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o): in function `UaClientSdk::UaReverseEndpointList::endpointCount()':
/home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:567: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::UaMutexLocker(UaMutex*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/buildbot/work/uasdkcpp/src/uaclient/uaclientcpp/uareverseconnect.cpp:567: undefined reference to `UaMutexLocker::~UaMutexLocker()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN11UaClientSdk17UaReverseEndpointE[_ZTVN11UaClientSdk17UaReverseEndpointE]+0x48): undefined reference to `UaThread::start()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib/libuaclientcppd.a(uareverseconnect.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN11UaClientSdk17UaReverseEndpointE[_ZTIN11UaClientSdk17UaReverseEndpointE]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for UaThread'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:30: aplikace] Chyba 1
The terminal process "bash '-c', '/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/examples/client_gettingstarted/lesson01/build.sh'" terminated with exit code: 2.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

My Makefile is. Does anyone have

```
cc=g++
cflags=-g -Wall 
libflags=-L/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/lib -luamoduled -luamodelsd -lcoremoduled -luabasecppd -luastackd -lxmlparsercppd -luapkicppd -luaclientcppd -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto
includes=-I/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/include/uabasecpp\
-I/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/include/uastack\
-I/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/include/uaclientcpp\
-I/home/michal/Dokumenty/OPCUA_adapter/sdk/include/uapkicpp\

objfiles=client_cpp_sdk_tutorial.o sampleclient.o
vystup=aplikace

%.o : %.cpp
    $(cc) $(cflags) $(includes) -c $<

# startovaci pravidlo
vychozi: $(vystup)

# zavislosti
dep:
    $(cc) -MM *.cpp >dep.list

-include dep.list

clean:

    rm aplikace $(objfiles)

# slinkování aplikace
$(vystup): $(objfiles)
    $(cc) $(cflags) $(objfiles) $(libflags) $(includes) -o $@
```

Comment: Can you place `-luaclientcppd`  in front of `-luabasecppd` ? Suspect the order could be a reason